# Migrating Mercurial to GitHub

Tags: python, git, mercurial, github

I want to move from Google Code and Mercurial to Git and GitHub while keeping all branches and version history.

So far it seems like the Hg-Git mercurial plugin (http://hg-git.github.com/) is my only option.  I tried to follow the install instructions but am in a little over my head.  Here's where I am:

- I installed [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/5/4/a54badb6-9c3f-478d-8657-93b3fc9fe62d/vcsetup.exe)
- I installed [Python 2.7.3](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/python-2.7.3.msi)
- I installed [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=57e1e64f6b7c7f1d2eddfc9746bbaf20)
- I added the following to my mercurial.ini in TortoiseHg:

```
[extensions]
hgext.bookmarks =
hggit =
```

Now when I run:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install.exe hg-git
```

I get the following:

```
Searching for hg-git
Best match: hg-git 0.3.3
Processing hg_git-0.3.3-py2.7.egg
hg-git 0.3.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages\hg_git-0.3.3-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for hg-git
Searching for dulwich>=0.8.0
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/dulwich/
Reading http://samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich
Reading http://launchpad.net/dulwich
Best match: dulwich 0.8.5
Downloading http://samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/dulwich-0.8.5.tar.gz
Processing dulwich-0.8.5.tar.gz
Running dulwich-0.8.5\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\lee\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3qgeev\dulwich-0.8.5\egg-dist-tmp-ciyt_4
```

And then a bunch of errors that look like this:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c11', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1712, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1700, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1716, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 211, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 446, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 481, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dists[0], deps, "Using")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 519, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 563, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 799, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
```

Not sure what to try next.  I also tried following tips from [Cloning github repo with hggit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432507/cloning-github-repo-with-hggit) but I'm missing something obvious.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look at: [Converting a Mercurial (hg) repository to Git on Windows (7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267232/converting-a-mercurial-hg-repository-to-git-on-windows-7)?

Comment: I remember I used Tailor (http://progetti.metapensiero.it/tailor) for some repository conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just draft and some notes&thoughts:

- In order to use TortoiseHG (on Windows, XP SP3 if it matter) Python is not mandatory - I work with THG without Python/setuptools/pip
- TortoiseHG ([32bit](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/files/downloads/tortoisehg-2.5.0-hg-2.3.1-x86.msi) or [64bit](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/files/downloads/tortoisehg-2.5.0-hg-2.3.1-x64.msi)) from Bitbucket are self-sufficient Mercurial in Windows-world
- I added hg-git extension to my TortoiseHG by hand

  - cloned hg-git from [bitbucket repo](http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git/) into local dir

> \TortoiseHg\plugins>dir /B
>
> hg-git
>
> ...

- added hg-git extension to global mercurial.ini (Documents and Settings\Badger\mercurial.ini)

> [extensions]
>
> ...
>
> hggit = c:\Program Files_Tools\TortoiseHg\plugins\hg-git\hggit
>
> ...

- bookmarks extension, as default extension, bundled with THG, was enabled in GUI some versions ago and can be found in mercurial.ini now as `bookmarks =` without corresponding checkbox in Settings-Extensions
- With functional hg-git in TortoiseHG (clone, pull, push without errors for *some Git-repo*) you can try to convert external Mercurial repo to external Git repo

  - clone CG Mercurial repo to local (Mercurial) repo
  - create new empty Git repo on Github (verify authentification and other possible issues)
  - add second remote repo (GUI - "Synchonize" tab, by hand - new string in `[paths]` section in repo's .hg\hgrc), for me only `git+ssh://git@github.com/username/reponame.git` URL (with key-based authentification over PageAnt) is transparent solution
  - push local repo to github
  - Have Fun

Screenshot is just example of my active Git repo on GitHub and attempt to illustrate my words by a live source

[image: Fiver Repo]

Comment: Thanks @Badger for the details.  First, by 'hgsubversion' in mercurial.ini, I assume you mean 'hggit'.  Now I'm a little further along.  When I type "% hg help hggit" in THG I get "hggit extension - no help text available". So I'm assuming the extension is good. But when I try to clone from github I get "No module named gitrepo". Any ideas?

Comment: @LeeRichardson - 1. yes, hgsubversion was my typo - I removed wrong line from copy&paste chunk 2. hggit **very basic** help can be reached by (surprise!!!) `hg help git` 3. Before github game (and not clone, I always use *only pull|push* pair), check hg-git work on some another repo

Comment: @Badger Been working on this for days with no luck.  I can now clone and pull just fine (an out of date THG was causing problems).  The push isn't working though.  When I try to push to github ('hg push git+ssh://git@github.com/lprichar/SirenOfShame.git') I get "abort: The handle is invalid".  I get the same when pushing to a local git repo. Do I need to include add dulwich to THG somehow?  Do I need to configure TortoiseHg to use TortoisePlink.exe for ssh? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @LeeRichardson - 1. THG **have** dulwich in core 2. `[ui]
ssh = "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe"` in mercurial.ini 3. Did you add and verify your public key to GitHub profile? 4. Try to push with `--debug --traceback` options 5. I don't know, why I haven't problems with my repo - all *just work as expected*

Comment: @LeeRichardson - I used http://jamesmckay.net/2010/06/tortoisehg-as-a-github-client-on-windows/ as quick-start guide

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Badger.  I never got past "The handle is invalid" error in THG, but with all your tips I eventually got it working from an msysgit command prompt.  Wow, what a pain this was.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with hg-git. I come up with a weird solution.

I imported hg repo with https://import.github.com/new
It is not weird and must be what you look for.

---

**The weird and bonus section is below:**

- I created a hg mirror repo on http://bitbucket.org
- I created a local hg repository within git repository.
- I added `.hg/` to my `.gitignore`
- Add `.hg/` and `.git/` to your `.gitignore` file

  `.git/
  .hg/`
- Enter the `.hg` directory in local repo and symlink your `.gitignore` file as `.hgignore` with

  $ ln -s ../.gitignore .hgignore
- Now any changes made to your `.gitignore` are considered also by `hg`

  $ git add .gitignore -am 'gitignore'

  $ hg add .gitignore -am 'Do not forget to symlink .gitignore as .hgignore in .hg/ folder'

  $ hg push default

  $ git push origin master

**Conclusion:** While it looks inefficient, it takes advantages of github while not losing hg repo and database and gives opportunity to use both `git` and `hg`

Comment: Obviously the hg and git repo are not going to exactly be in sync, lest you be really deliberate and sync atomic clocks across terminals. Still, I wish developers made some attempt at allowing multiple DVCS methodologies, maybe each method could be a (blog timeline) different perspective of the repository root, spoken in multiple languages. The HG version commit log could mention the Git version is keeping a different timeline and vice versa, keeping each power in check.